# Hibernate Criterion on joined table showing unexpected results

Tags: java, hibernate, join, criteria

I have a criteria that looks like this:

```
public List<role> searchByFormStatus(boolean status) {
    Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass());
    List<role> result = (List<role>) criteria                               
                        .setFetchMode("role", FetchMode.JOIN)
                        .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                        .createAlias("formApprovals", "f")
                        .add(Restrictions. eq("f.latestApproval", true))
                        .list();
    return result;                          
}
```

At first look it should be working, but no matter if I send true or false value in the parameter, the result will always be

```
[{
    "roleIsActive": true,
    "roleName": "role1",
    "roleNotes": "note",
    "formApprovals": [
        {
            "approvalNotes": "good",
            "approvedDate": 1449900000000,
            "fkapprovedBy": 1,
            "idformApproval": 1,
            "latestApproval": true
        },
        {
            "approvalNotes": "bad",
            "approvedDate": 1449900000000,
            "fkapprovedBy": 1,
            "idformApproval": 2,
            "latestApproval": false
        }
}]
```

As you can see, the "formApprovals" brings all registers in the database, even if I create the restriction for the latestApproval property

The property declaration in the parent object (role) is:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="role")
public Set<FormApproval> getFormApprovals() {
    return this.formApprovals;
}

public void setFormApprovals(Set<FormApproval> formApprovals) {
    this.formApprovals = formApprovals;
}
```

Checking the console, I can see that the where clause is being generated properly by hibernate, however, I can see that after that there are other queries, is it possible that those queries (I have no idea why are they there) are overwriting my criteria?

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

FormApproval Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FormApproval"
    ,catalog="catalog"
)
public class FormApproval  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8L;
     private int idformApproval;
     private role role;
     private Integer fkapprovedBy;
     private Date approvedDate;
     private String approvalNotes;
     private boolean latestApproval;

    public FormApproval() {
    }


    public FormApproval(int idformApproval, role role) {
        this.idformApproval = idformApproval;
        this.role = role;
    }
    public FormApproval(int idformApproval, role role, Integer fkapprovedBy, Date approvedDate, String approvalNotes, boolean latestApproval) {
       this.idformApproval = idformApproval;
       this.role = role;
       this.fkapprovedBy = fkapprovedBy;
       this.approvedDate = approvedDate;
       this.approvalNotes = approvalNotes;
       this.latestApproval = latestApproval; 
    }

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY) 

    @Column(name="IDFormApproval", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public int getIdformApproval() {
        return this.idformApproval;
    }

    public void setIdformApproval(int idformApproval) {
        this.idformApproval = idformApproval;
    }

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="FKRole", nullable=false)
    public role getrole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setrole(role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


    @Column(name="LatestApproval")
    public boolean getLatestApproval() {
        return this.latestApproval;
    }

    public void setLatestApproval(boolean latestApproval) {
        this.latestApproval = latestApproval;
    }

    @Column(name="FKApprovedBy")
    public Integer getFkapprovedBy() {
        return this.fkapprovedBy;
    }

    public void setFkapprovedBy(Integer fkapprovedBy) {
        this.fkapprovedBy = fkapprovedBy;
    }
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="ApprovedDate", length=10)
    public Date getApprovedDate() {
        return this.approvedDate;
    }

    public void setApprovedDate(Date approvedDate) {
        this.approvedDate = approvedDate;
    }

    @Column(name="ApprovalNotes")
    public String getApprovalNotes() {
        return this.approvalNotes;
    }

    public void setApprovalNotes(String approvalNotes) {
        this.approvalNotes = approvalNotes;
    }
}
```

Role Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Role"
    ,catalog="catalog"
)    
public class Role  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idRole;
     private WorkType workType;
     private String roleName;
     private String roleNotes;
     private boolean roleIsActive;
     private Set<FormApproval> formApprovals = new HashSet<FormApproval>(0);
     private Set<Topicrole> topicRoles = new HashSet<TopicRole>(0);
     private Set<FormFeedBack> formFeedBacks = new HashSet<FormFeedBack>(0);
     private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRrole>(0);
     private Set<Interview> interviews = new HashSet<Interview>(0);

    public Role() {
    }


    public Role(int idRole, WorkType workType, String roleName, boolean roleIsActive) {
        this.idRole = idRole;
        this.workType = workType;
        this.RoleName = RoleName;
        this.roleIsActive = roleIsActive;
    }
    public Role(int idRole, WorkType workType, String roleName, String roleNotes, boolean roleIsActive, Set<FormApproval> formApprovals, Set<TopicRole> topicRoles, Set<FormFeedBack> formFeedBacks, Set<UserRole> userRoles, Set<Interview> interviews) {
       this.idRole = idRole;
       this.workType = workType;
       this.RoleName = RoleName;
       this.roleNotes = roleNotes;
       this.roleIsActive = roleIsActive;
       this.formApprovals = formApprovals;
       this.topicRoles = topicRoles;
       this.formFeedBacks = formFeedBacks;
       this.userRoles = userRoles;
       this.interviews = interviews;
    }

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY) 

    @Column(name="IDRole", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public int getIdrole() {
        return this.idRole;
    }

    public void setIdrole(int idRole) {
        this.idRole = idRole;
    }
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="FKWorkType", nullable=false)
    public WorkType getWorkType() {
        return this.workType;
    }

    public void setWorkType(WorkType workType) {
        this.workType = workType;
    }

    @Column(name="RoleName", nullable=false)
    public String getRoleName() {
        return this.roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    @Column(name="RoleNotes")
    public String getRoleNotes() {
        return this.roleNotes;
    }

    public void setRoleNotes(String roleNotes) {
        this.roleNotes = roleNotes;
    }

    @Column(name="RoleIsActive", nullable=false)
    public boolean isRoleIsActive() {
        return this.roleIsActive;
    }

    public void setRoleIsActive(boolean roleIsActive) {
        this.roleIsActive = roleIsActive;
    }

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="role")
    public Set<FormApproval> getFormApprovals() {
        return this.formApprovals;
    }

    public void setFormApprovals(Set<FormApproval> formApprovals) {
        this.formApprovals = formApprovals;
    }

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="role")
    public Set<TopicRole> getTopicRoles() {
        return this.topicRoles;
    }

    public void setTopicRoles(Set<TopicRole> topicRoles) {
        this.topicRoles = topicRoles;
    }

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="role")
@JsonManagedReference
    public Set<FormFeedBack> getFormFeedBacks() {
        return this.formFeedBacks;
    }

    public void setFormFeedBacks(Set<FormFeedBack> formFeedBacks) {
        this.formFeedBacks = formFeedBacks;
    }

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="role")
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return this.userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="acnrole")
    public Set<Interview> getInterviews() {
        return this.interviews;
    }

    public void setInterviews(Set<Interview> interviews) {
        this.interviews = interviews;
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you add your FormApproval fields with annotations to the question?  Why do you need to set the fetch mode and result transformer?

Comment: @JohnScattergood done!  the fetchmode and resulttransformer are there because I was having trouble with the query that was being generated with an Inner Join, but I needed Left Outer Join, and that solved the problem

Comment: You needed left outer join because role.formApprovals could be null? Did you try to add the fetch mode as part of createAlias() instead?

Comment: Try using Boolean instead boolean and corresponding setter and getter in your FormApproval Entity, I am just guessing this might or might not help .

Comment: yeah, tried FetchMode.EAGER but says it's deprecated so I used JOIN and looks like it doesn't match the arguments (String, String, FetchMode).

Comment: changing boolean to Boolean didn't work either

Comment: Does it add the restriction to the ON clause? It should be part of ON when you are using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using

```
.createCriteria("formApprovals","f",1,Restrictions.eq("f.latestApproval", status))
```

1 forces a Left outer join in the query

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the restriction as part of `ON` clause on top of the association.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="role")
@Where(clause=" latestApproval='true' ")
public Set<FormApproval> getFormApprovals() {
    return this.formApprovals;
}
```

Also you can eliminate setting `FetchMode.JOIN` fetch by pointing to the association path using the method `org.hibernate.Criteria.createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, JoinType joinType)`

```
public List<role> searchByFormStatus(boolean status) {
    Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Role.class, "role")
            .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .createAlias("role.formApprovals", "formApprovals", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

**Update:**

For older versions of hibernate, use the other method below. Where `joinType` value would be 1 for `LEFT_OUTER_JOIN` and join clause can be passed as the 4th argument.

```
public Criteria createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType, Criterion withClause) throws HibernateException;
```

Comment: when I add the  JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN to the createAlias, i get an error that the arguments are not valid, seems like JoinType sends an integer.

Is there any way that

@Where(clause=" latestApproval='true' ")

gets a dynamic value?

Comment: It should take only `JoinType` enum as an argument, what's the exception you see?

Comment: The method createAlias(String, String, int) in the type Criteria is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, JoinType)

Comment: Oh I see that it's the deprecated method, what version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: Also note that there is another method where you can pass the join clause to make it dynamic, the value for `LEFT_OUTER_JOIN` is 1 `public Criteria createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType, Criterion withClause) throws HibernateException;`

Comment: when I made the changes and tested the query it throw the error: could not resolve property: role of: com.dpcs.internal.prj.domain.role

Comment: Could you post the entire Role class? `Role` class may have been nested with `role` which is not required for this case. Please make sure the class name starts with upper case R as per convention.

Comment: Also make sure you don't forget to modify createCriteria to this `.createCriteria(Role.class, "role")` so you can point the association path of child object using the alias of parent (role).

Comment: Fixed! createCriteria(class,String) didn;t work but i tried createCriteria(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType, Criterion withClause) and now it is working properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With EAGER fetch types, a nested criteria should work for this case:

```
public List<role> searchByFormStatus(boolean status) {
    Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass());
    List<role> result = (List<role>) criteria                               
                        .createCriteria("formApprovals")
                             .add(Restrictions.eq("latestApproval", true))
                        .list();
    return result;                          
}
```

Comment: It keeps retrieving all the formApprovals data

Comment: Even ones with latestApproval != true

Comment: yes, is like the condition is being overwritten somewhere